# C# - Supporting non-dense ranking in a red black tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search-tree, ranking, red-black-tree

The following is a C# adaptation of an implementation of a left leaning Red Black Tree found in Princeton's course material. Original comments have been stripped to save visual space. The tree stores multiple values in a single node using a HashSet in order to track duplicate values from different sources.

Right now, `Rank()` is dense. We're using SQL Server terminology, so what we mean by dense is that given the values `[1,1,2,3]`, a dense rank for the value of 1 would be ranked 1st, 2 would be 2nd, and 3 would be 3rd. A non-dense rank would yield: 1 as 1st, 2 as 3rd, 3 as 4th. In other words, duplicates are counted towards the proceeding rank.

How can we achieve this?

I've added a `boolean dense` argument to the rank, so we may do a dense rank optionally. The implementation given below is broken and does not work as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Example
{
    public class RankTree<TKey, TValue>
    {

        private static bool RED = true;
        private static bool BLACK = false;
        private Node root;
        private IComparer<TKey> comparer;

        private class Node
        {

            public TKey key;
            public HashSet<TValue> values;
            public Node left;
            public Node right;
            public bool color;
            public int size;
            public int duplicates = 0;

            public Node(TKey key, bool color, int size)
            {
                this.key = key;
                this.values = new HashSet<TValue>();
                this.color = color;
                this.size = size;
            }

            public void AddValue(TValue val)
            {
                this.values.Add(val);
            }

            public void RemoveValue(TValue val)
            {
                this.values.Remove(val);
            }
        }

        public RankTree(IComparer<TKey> comparer) {
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }

        //  is node x red; false if x is null ?
        private bool IsRed(Node x)
        {
            if (x == null) return false;
            return (x.color == RED);
        }

        public int Duplicates() {
            return Duplicates(this.root);
        }
        private int Duplicates(Node x)
        {
            if (x == null) return 0;
            return x.duplicates;
        }

        //  number of node in subtree rooted at x; 0 if x is null
        private int Size(Node x)
        {
            if (x == null) return 0;
            return x.size;
        }

        public int Size()
        {
            return Size(this.root);
        }

        public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return this.root == null;
        }

        public HashSet<TValue> Get(TKey key)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new NullReferenceException("argument to get() is null");
            return Get(this.root, key);
        }

        //  value associated with the given key in subtree rooted at x; null if no such key
        private HashSet<TValue> Get(Node x, TKey key)
        {
            while (x != null)
            {
                int cmp = comparer.Compare(key, x.key);
                if (cmp < 0) x = x.left;
                else if (cmp > 0) x = x.right;
                else return x.values;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public bool Contains(TKey key)
        {
            return Get(key) != null;
        }

        public void Put(TKey key, TValue val)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new NullReferenceException("first argument to put() is null");

            if (val == null)
            {
                Delete(key, val);
                return;
            }

            this.root = Put(this.root, key, val);
            this.root.color = BLACK;
            //  assert check();
        }

        //  insert the key-value pair in the subtree rooted at h
        private Node Put(Node h, TKey key, TValue val)
        {
            if (h == null)
            {
                Node node = new Node(key, RED, 1);
                node.AddValue(val);
                return node;
            }

            int cmp = comparer.Compare(key, h.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
            {
                h.left = Put(h.left, key, val);
            }
            else if (cmp > 0)
            {
                h.right = Put(h.right, key, val);
            }
            else {
                h.AddValue(val);
            }

            //  fix-up any right-leaning links
            if (IsRed(h.right) && !IsRed(h.left)) h = RotateLeft(h);
            if (IsRed(h.left) && IsRed(h.left.left)) h = RotateRight(h);
            if (IsRed(h.left) && IsRed(h.right)) FlipColors(h);

            h.size = Size(h.left) + Size(h.right) + 1;
            h.duplicates = Duplicates(h.left) + Duplicates(h.right) + h.values.Count - 1;
            return h;
        }

        public void DeleteMin()
        {
            if (IsEmpty()) return;

            if (!IsRed(this.root.left) && !IsRed(this.root.right))
            {
                this.root.color = RED;
            }

            this.root = DeleteMin(this.root);
            if (!IsEmpty())
            {
                this.root.color = BLACK;
            }

            //  assert check();
        }

        //  delete the key-value pair with the minimum key rooted at h
        private Node DeleteMin(Node h)
        {
            if (h.left == null) return null;

            if (!IsRed(h.left) && !IsRed(h.left.left)) h = MoveRedLeft(h);

            h.left = DeleteMin(h.left);
            return Balance(h);
        }

        public void DeleteMax()
        {
            if (IsEmpty()) return;

            if (!IsRed(this.root.left) && !IsRed(this.root.right)) this.root.color = RED;

            this.root = DeleteMax(this.root);
            if (!IsEmpty())
            {
                this.root.color = BLACK;
            }

            //  assert check();
        }

        //  delete the key-value pair with the maximum key rooted at h
        private Node DeleteMax(Node h)
        {
            if (IsRed(h.left)) h = RotateRight(h);
            if (h.right == null) return null;

            if (!IsRed(h.right) && !IsRed(h.right.left)) h = MoveRedRight(h);

            h.right = DeleteMax(h.right);
            return Balance(h);
        }

        public void Delete(TKey key, TValue val)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new NullReferenceException("argument to delete() is null");

            if (!Contains(key)) return;

            //  if both children of root are black, set root to red
            if (!IsRed(this.root.left) && !IsRed(this.root.right)) this.root.color = RED;

            this.root = Delete(this.root, key, val);
            if (!IsEmpty()) this.root.color = BLACK;

            //  assert check();
        }

        //  delete the key-value pair with the given key rooted at h
        private Node Delete(Node h, TKey key, TValue val)
        {
            //  assert get(h, key) != null;
            if (comparer.Compare(key, h.key) < 0)
            {
                if (!IsRed(h.left) && !IsRed(h.left.left)) h = MoveRedLeft(h);
                h.left = Delete(h.left, key, val);
            }
            else {
                if (IsRed(h.left)) h = RotateRight(h);
                if (comparer.Compare(key, h.key) == 0 && h.right == null) return null;
                if (!IsRed(h.right) && !IsRed(h.right.left)) h = MoveRedRight(h);

                if (comparer.Compare(key, h.key) == 0)
                {
                    Node x = Min(h.right);
                    h.key = x.key;
                    h.values = x.values; // FIXME: Potentially wrong?
                                        //  h.val = get(h.right, min(h.right).key);
                                        //  h.key = min(h.right).key;
                    h.right = DeleteMin(h.right);
                }
                else {
                    h.right = Delete(h.right, key, val);
                }
            }

            return Balance(h);
        }

        //  make a left-leaning link lean to the right
        private Node RotateRight(Node h)
        {
            //  assert (h != null) && isRed(h.left);
            Node x = h.left;
            h.left = x.right;
            x.right = h;
            x.color = x.right.color;
            x.right.color = RED;
            x.size = h.size;
            x.duplicates = h.duplicates;
            h.size = Size(h.left) + Size(h.right) + 1;
            h.duplicates = Duplicates(h.left) + Duplicates(h.right) + h.values.Count - 1;
            return x;
        }

        //  make a right-leaning link lean to the left
        private Node RotateLeft(Node h)
        {
            //  assert (h != null) && isRed(h.right);
            Node x = h.right;
            h.right = x.left;
            x.left = h;
            x.color = x.left.color;
            x.left.color = RED;
            x.size = h.size;
            x.duplicates = h.duplicates;
            h.size = Size(h.left) + Size(h.right) + 1;
            h.duplicates = Duplicates(h.left) + Duplicates(h.right) + h.values.Count - 1;
            return x;
        }

        //  flip the colors of a node and its two children
        private void FlipColors(Node h)
        {
            //  h must have opposite color of its two children
            //  assert (h != null) && (h.left != null) && (h.right != null);
            //  assert (!isRed(h) &&  isRed(h.left) &&  isRed(h.right))
            //     || (isRed(h)  && !isRed(h.left) && !isRed(h.right));
            h.color = !h.color;
            h.left.color = !h.left.color;
            h.right.color = !h.right.color;
        }

        //  Assuming that h is red and both h.left and h.left.left
        //  are black, make h.left or one of its children red.
        private Node MoveRedLeft(Node h)
        {
            //  assert (h != null);
            //  assert isRed(h) && !isRed(h.left) && !isRed(h.left.left);
            FlipColors(h);
            if (IsRed(h.right.left))
            {
                h.right = RotateRight(h.right);
                h = RotateLeft(h);
                FlipColors(h);
            }

            return h;
        }

        //  Assuming that h is red and both h.right and h.right.left
        //  are black, make h.right or one of its children red.
        private Node MoveRedRight(Node h)
        {
            //  assert (h != null);
            //  assert isRed(h) && !isRed(h.right) && !isRed(h.right.left);
            FlipColors(h);
            if (IsRed(h.left.left))
            {
                h = RotateRight(h);
                FlipColors(h);
            }

            return h;
        }

        //  restore red-black tree invariant
        private Node Balance(Node h)
        {
            //  assert (h != null);
            if (IsRed(h.right)) h = RotateLeft(h);
            if (IsRed(h.left) && IsRed(h.left.left)) h = RotateRight(h);
            if (IsRed(h.left) && IsRed(h.right)) FlipColors(h);

            h.size = Size(h.left) + Size(h.right) + 1;
            h.duplicates = Duplicates(h.left) + Duplicates(h.right) + h.values.Count - 1;
            return h;
        }

        public int Height()
        {
            return Height(this.root);
        }

        private int Height(Node x)
        {
            if (x == null) return -1;
            return 1 + Math.Max(Height(x.left), Height(x.right));
        }

        public TKey Min()
        {
            if (IsEmpty()) return default(TKey);
            return Min(this.root).key;
        }

        //  the smallest key in subtree rooted at x; null if no such key
        private Node Min(Node x)
        {
            //  assert x != null;
            if (x.left == null) return x;
            else return Min(x.left);
        }

        public TKey Max()
        {
            if (IsEmpty()) return default(TKey);
            return Max(this.root).key;
        }

        //  the largest key in the subtree rooted at x; null if no such key
        private Node Max(Node x)
        {
            //  assert x != null;
            if (x.right == null) return x;
            else return Max(x.right);
        }

        public TKey Floor(TKey key)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new NullReferenceException("argument to floor() is null");

            if (IsEmpty()) return default(TKey);

            Node x = Floor(this.root, key);
            if (x == null) return default(TKey);
            else return x.key;
        }

        //  the largest key in the subtree rooted at x less than or equal to the given key
        private Node Floor(Node x, TKey key)
        {
            if (x == null) return null;

            int cmp = comparer.Compare(key, x.key);
            if (cmp == 0) return x;

            if (cmp < 0) return Floor(x.left, key);

            Node t = Floor(x.right, key);
            if (t != null) return t;
            else return x;
        }

        public TKey Ceiling(TKey key)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new NullReferenceException("argument to ceiling() is null");

            if (IsEmpty()) return default(TKey);

            Node x = Ceiling(this.root, key);
            if (x == null) return default(TKey);
            else return x.key;
        }

        //  the smallest key in the subtree rooted at x greater than or equal to the given key
        private Node Ceiling(Node x, TKey key)
        {
            if (x == null) return null;

            int cmp = comparer.Compare(key, x.key);
            if (cmp == 0) return x;

            if (cmp > 0) return Ceiling(x.right, key);

            Node t = Ceiling(x.left, key);
            if (t != null) return t;
            else return x;
        }

        public TKey Select(int k)
        {
            if (k < 0 || k >= Size()) throw new ArgumentException();

            Node x = Select(this.root, k);
            return x.key;
        }

        //  the key of rank k in the subtree rooted at x
        private Node Select(Node x, int k)
        {
            //  assert x != null;
            //  assert k >= 0 && k < size(x);
            int t = Size(x.left);
            if (t > k) return Select(x.left, k);
            else if (t < k) return Select(x.right, (k - (t - 1)));
            else return x;
        }

        public int Rank(TKey key)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new NullReferenceException("argument to rank() is null");
            return Rank(key, true);
        }

        public int Rank(TKey key, bool dense)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new NullReferenceException("argument to rank() is null");
            return Rank(key, this.root, dense);
        }

        //  number of keys less than key in the subtree rooted at x
        private int Rank(TKey key, Node x, bool dense)
        {
            if (x == null) return 0;

            int cmp = comparer.Compare(key, x.key);
            //         StdOut.println(x.key + ": " + duplicates(x.left));
            if (cmp < 0) return Rank(key, x.left, dense);
            else if (cmp > 0) return 1 + Size(x.left) + (dense ? 0 : Duplicates(x.left)) + Rank(key, x.right, dense);
            else return Size(x.left) + (dense ? 0 : Duplicates(x.left));
        }

        public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys()
        {
            if (IsEmpty()) return new Queue<TKey>();

            return Keys(Min(), Max());
        }

        public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys(TKey lo, TKey hi)
        {
            if (lo == null) throw new NullReferenceException("first argument to keys() is null");
            if (hi == null) throw new NullReferenceException("second argument to keys() is null");

            Queue<TKey> queue = new Queue<TKey>();
            //  if (isEmpty() || lo.compareTo(hi) > 0) return queue;
            Keys(this.root, queue, lo, hi);
            return queue;
        }

        //  add the keys between lo and hi in the subtree rooted at x
        //  to the queue
        private void Keys(Node x, Queue<TKey> queue, TKey lo, TKey hi)
        {
            if (x == null) return;

            int cmplo = comparer.Compare(lo, x.key);
            int cmphi = comparer.Compare(hi, x.key);
            if (cmplo < 0)
            {
                Keys(x.left, queue, lo, hi);
            }

            if (cmplo <= 0 && cmphi >= 0)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(x.key);
            }

            if (cmphi > 0)
            {
                Keys(x.right, queue, lo, hi);
            }
        }

        public int Size(TKey lo, TKey hi)
        {
            if (lo == null) throw new NullReferenceException("first argument to size() is null");
            if (hi == null) throw new NullReferenceException("second argument to size() is null");

            if (comparer.Compare(lo, hi) > 0) return 0;
            if (Contains(hi)) return Rank(hi) - Rank(lo) + 1;
            else return Rank(hi) - Rank(lo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are almost there you should only tweak Rank/Size/Duplicate function. It doesn't matter that it is RB tree it will work the same with plain binary tree so you may start with that. Non dense rank is equivalent to number of values in tree less than curr value. Generally there are 3 cases in recursive implementation: `key` is less than curr node - then just compute rank for left subtree and return it, key is equal then return number of values in left subtree, key is greater then return number of values in left subtree + number of values in curr node + rank in right node.

Comment: @csharpfolk Thanks for the guidance, we got it working thanks to your description. Cheers!